# How to submit Python request to Thomson Reuters Open Calais API

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have some Python code on Google App Engine (gae) which makes a request to the Thomson Reuters Open Calais API: it sends some plain text as data and should in return obtain a JSON object with the tags corresponding to the text. Unfortunately, all I'm getting is an error 500 along with the following error message in the gae console:

[image]

The above error seems to take place in Werkzeug, which is a Python WSGI Utility Library (whatever WSGI means!). The error arises on line 117 [here](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/_compat.py), so maybe this means that the charset is missing, but I don't know where in my Python code I should set the charset.

I'd be most grateful if anyone could help me solve this problem.

Here is my Python code:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

calais_url = "https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/calais"

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
    data = "The 'In' camp holds a one-point lead ahead of Britain's June 23 referendum on whether the country should remain in the European Union, according to an online opinion poll by YouGov released on Friday.The poll found support for 'In' stood at 40 percent, while 39 percent intended to vote 'Out', 16 percent were undecided and 5 percent did not intend to vote.The poll of 3,371 people was conducted between April 12 and 14 and the results were similar to those seen in other recent YouGov polls. The previous one, conducted on April 11-12, found 'In' and 'Out' were tied on 39 percent with 17 percent undecided."
    headers = {'X-AG-Access-Token' : 'my_secret_key', 'Content-Type' : 'text/raw', 'outputFormat' : 'application/json', 'omitOutputtingOriginalText' : 'true'}
    try:
        sendArticleText(data, headers)
    except Exception ,e:
        return 'Error in connect ' , e

def sendArticleText(_data, _headers):
    response = urlfetch.fetch(calais_url, payload=_data , method=POST, headers=_headers, deadline=60)
    content = response.text
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return content.json()

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 404 error."""
    return 'Sorry, Nothing at this URL.', 404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 500 error."""
    return 'Sorry, unexpected error:\n{}'.format(e), 500
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're returning a tuple from `main`, and if view function returns a tuple, flask expects 2nd member in tuple to be http status code, not exception value.

Instead of

```
return 'Error in connect ' , e
```

Line 15 should be something like this:

```
return 'Error in connect: {}'.format(e)
```

This will allow you to see the real error.

Comment: Thank you @notapresent. Your tip is extremely helpful. Apparently, the response being returned by urlfetch doesn't have a 'text' attribute! [link](http://imgur.com/WroLgwn)

Comment: I modified the sendArticleText() function to return response directly instead of content and now I'm getting the following error message in the gae console: [error msg](http://imgur.com/0JxCrHc). Not sure what is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working!

Special thanks to Shobhit from the Google Cloud Platform and @notapresent for their help.

Here is the final code:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

calais_url = "https://api.thomsonreuters.com/permid/calais"
headers = {'X-AG-Access-Token' : 'my_secret_key', 'Content-Type' : 'text/raw', 'outputFormat' : 'application/json', 'omitOutputtingOriginalText' : 'true'}

def sendArticleText(_data, _headers):
    response = urlfetch.Fetch(calais_url, payload=_data , method=urlfetch.POST, headers=_headers, deadline=80)
    content = response.content
    return content

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def main():
    request.get_data()
    article = request.data
    try:
        result = sendArticleText(article, headers)
    except Exception ,e:
        return 'Error in connect: {}'.format(e)
    return result

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 404 error."""
    return 'Sorry, Nothing at this URL.', 404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def page_not_found(e):
    """Return a custom 500 error."""
    return 'Sorry, unexpected error:\n {}'.format(e), 500
```